# Articles and books on aspects

Tags: reference-request, aspect

I am searching for a good book on different aspects, which would include different types of aspects, not just perfective and imperfective, but deductive, inferential, retrospective, inceptive and many others. I would be very happy if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Have you seen Binnick 2001? http://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/~binnick/old%20tense/List.pdf If I were you, I would start with Comrie 1987 or The Oxford Handbook of Tense and Aspect http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780195381979.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780195381979

Comment: Thank's a lot. I've read a lot of litreature on aspect as a general topic. In most of the books and articles authors are talking about perfective, Imperfective, habitual, zero and sometimes progressive aspects. Comrie is also one of them, but I do not reject the fact that it is the best book to start. I have scanned the  Oxford hand book if tense and aspect too and it also looked as it is more general than specific. What I am searching for is more specific or may be it is better to say rare in studies.  I am looking for such aspects as inceptive, completive, types of inferential aspects and so

Comment: There are a lot of aspect types in Cinque's tree. I am interested in them, but I couldn't find sources except of the Cinque's book.

Comment: This is too broad because it is a list question.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically on aspect, [Comrie's 1987 *Aspect*](http://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~filip/Comrie.Aspect.pdf), 3rd printing,
in the Cambridge Textbooks in Linguistics series.

To fit aspect into the framework of the rest of linguistic semantics, Frawley's 1992 *Linguistic Semantics*,
from Erlbaum. Here's

- [an outline of Chapter 3](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/FrawleyEntities.pdf) in Frawley 1992 (on Entities, i.e, nouns),
- a list of [questions and topics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/frawleyq.pdf) for study in the book, and
- [a pdf of the first chapter](http://www.um.es/lincoing/jv/UNIT1.pdf), to give you a flavor

Comment: imho Frawley 1992 is the best textbook on semantics.

Comment: I agree. I also used Foley, _Anthropological Linguistics,_ to give a different viewpoint on roughly the same facts and see how pragmatics and cultural matters fit in.

Comment: This is a [syllabus, with references,](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/420syllabus04.pdf) from the last time I taught the course at Michigan (ten years ago, as it happens). It was a senior-level course - Linguistics 420 'Word and Metaphor' - and normally only linguistics majors and the odd logician took it.